# Angular JS - Issue while separating Services.js

Tags: angularjs

```
//I have a base.js 
//and a services.js in My angular App
//but when I move the code to Services.js. The Application Breaks

//But the same when I move the services to a different file "Services.js"

//..........App.js -

var App = angular.module("App", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ngAnimate", "toastr"]);

App.service("utilServices", window.commonServices);

App.controller("baseController", window.baseController);

//.........Services.js

var mem = {};
window.commonServices = function($rootScope, toastr) {
return {
storeVal: function(key, value) {
mem[key] = value;
},
fetchVal: function(key) {
return mem[key];
},
showAlert: function(msg, msgType, appVal) {
if (msgType === "success") {
return toastr.success(msg, appVal);
}
return false;
}
};
};
window.commonServices.$inject = ["$rootScope", "toastr"];
```

I get this error in the developer console of My Browser (Chrome) -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:4485)
at Object. (angular.js:4346)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4478)
at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4330)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4478)
at angular.js:4295
at getService (angular.js:4437)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4469)
at extend.instance (angular.js:9136)
at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8248)
```

This only occurs when I move the code of service to a separate a file and not when it is declared within the app.js file. I think it has something to do with the $.inject. I'm still a newbie learning the ropes. Any Help would be greatly appreciated Smile . :)

Comment: when you moving service to another file, have you added dependency to module? like `var App = angular.module("App", ["YOUR_SERVICE, ..."])` ?

Comment: var App = angular.module("App", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ngAnimate", "toastr","utilServices"]);

Like this . ?

Comment: yes, you are right. So ?

Comment: var mem = {};
window.commonServices = function($rootScope, toastr) {
return {
storeVal: function(key, value) {
mem[key] = value;
},
fetchVal: function(key) {
return mem[key];
},
showAlert: function(msg, msgType, appVal) {
if (msgType === "success") {
return toastr.success(msg, appVal);
}
return false;
}
};
};
window.commonServices.$inject = ["$rootScope", "toastr"];


This is all that is there in the Services.js file. . What modifications should i do .  Sorry for being a total Noob

Answer (score 0):

Well. You have module, defined in `app.js`:

```
var App = angular.module("App", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ngAnimate", "toastr"]);
```

You want to move service to separate file `services.js`.

For doing this you can do next (in `services.js`):

1) **define service module**:

```
var myServices = angular.module("utilServices", ["YOUR_DEPENDENCIES"]);
```

2) according to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services **register your service** in `services.js` and **add dependencies**:

```
myServices.factory('serviceId', ['$rootScope, toastr', function($rootScope, toastr) {
    return {
        storeVal: function(key, value) {
            mem[key] = value;
        },
        fetchVal: function(key) {
            return mem[key];
        },
        showAlert: function(msg, msgType, appVal) {
            if (msgType === "success") {
                return toastr.success(msg, appVal);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}]);
```

If dependencies above wouldn't work, try to add toastr directly to module like this (I'm not work with toastr, but I have seen [this](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) before post this answer):

```
angular.module('your_app', ['...', 'toastr']);
```

3) Now return to `app.js` and add dependency of your services to it like below:

```
var App = angular.module("App", ["utilServices", "ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ngAnimate", "toastr"]);
```

4) You can also using one module, if your application is small.

Then instead of `myServices` just use `App`.

Comment: Thanks for the time taken to send this. Its appreciated a lot. . This is what I have already done with my other services . . I mean I have them made to be angular.factory.
I wanted to learn angular.service :)

Comment: I mean I have successfully moved the factories.js file . The issue comes up only with Services.js which for some reason don't behave like this ..
Also You were spot on Sir. I did use the exact same library for toastr . .It is working smoothly :)

Comment: Thank You Sergio , Though It was a alight alteration from my requirement . I'm really grateful for your efforts :)